# Binding unbeforeunload method again to a refreshed popup window

Tags: javascript, reference, refresh, popupwindow

I have a popup window, and if I refresh it loses unbeforeunload callback. What is the right way to bind unbeforeunload method to refreshed popup window ?

```
var url = ...,
    title = ...,
    params = [
    "height=" + screen.height,
    "width=" + screen.width,
    "fullscreen=yes",
    "resizable=yes",
    "scrollbars=yes",
    "toolbar=yes",
    "menubar=yes",
    "location=yes"
    ].join(",");

    var popup = window.open(url, title, params),
        onbeforeunloadCallback = function (e) {
                  var isRefresh = this.opener.title == undefined;

                  if (isRefresh) {
                     // It doesn't work for second refresh
                     // so what am I doing wrong ?
                     console.log("It is refreshing");

                     popup.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunloadCallback;
                  }
        };

popup.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunloadCallback;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the code below is solved my problem. Please note that the function below is inside success of an ajax call, so `data.ParametersGuid` is a value returned from ajax. I'm also using this value to differentiate multiple popups from each other as can be seen in the code below:

```
var url = ...,
    title = ...,
    params = [
    "height=" + screen.height,
    "width=" + screen.width,
    "fullscreen=yes",
    "resizable=yes",
    "scrollbars=yes",
    "toolbar=yes",
    "menubar=yes",
    "location=yes"
    ].join(",");

var isRefresh = false,
popup = window.open(options.url, options.title, params),
getCurrentPopup = function () {
    var possibleCurrentPopupHandler = $.grep(window.popups, function (o) { return o.id === data.ParametersGuid }),
        currentPopup = possibleCurrentPopupHandler.length > 0 ? possibleCurrentPopupHandler[0].popup : null;

    return currentPopup;
},
setPopupCallbacks = function (p) {
    p = p != null ? p : getCurrentPopup();

    if (p == null) return;

    console.log("setPopupCallbacks -----");

    p.onload = onloadCallback;
    p.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunloadCallback;
    p.onunload = onunloadCallback;
    p.onkeydown = onkeydownCallback;
},
onloadCallback = function (e) {
    console.log("I'm in onloadCallback func");

    setPopupCallbacks();
},
onbeforeunloadCallback = function (e) {
    if (isRefresh) {
        console.log("I'm refreshed in onbeforeunloadCallback func");

        isRefresh = false;
        setPopupCallbacks();
    } else { // popup is being closed
        console.log("I'm about to close in onbeforeunloadCallback func");

        window.popups = $.grep(window.popups, function (o) { return o.id !== data.ParametersGuid });
        element.clientModel.deleteSessionParameters(data.ParametersGuid);
    }
},
onunloadCallback = function (e) {
    console.log("I'm in onunloadCallback func");

    setTimeout(function () { setPopupCallbacks(); }, 500);
},
onkeydownCallback = function (e) {      
    var ctrlRClick = e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey,
        f5Click = (e.which || e.keyCode) == 116;

    isRefresh = ctrlRClick || f5Click;
};

setPopupCallbacks(popup);

window.popups = window.popups || [];
window.popups.push({
    id: data.ParametersGuid,
    popup: popup
});
```